# both + [plural NP] + and + [singular NP]

Tags: grammar

Is it OK to use *both* followed by [plural NP] + and + [singular NP]?

Example:

> This solution requires *both computer skills and time commitment* that many users don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is OK. But you need to add an article to the second item:

> This solution requires both computer skills and **a** time commitment that many users don't have.

Because separately you would write them:

> This solution requires **computer skills** that many users don't have.
>   This solution requires **a time commitment** that many users don't have.